# Can I work abroad (Europe) for a U.S. company?

Tags: software-industry, europe, travel, remote-work

As the title says can I stay in Europe for a couple weeks to a month while working for a U.S. company?  I do not plan on staying for more than a month in Europe, but if possible, would like to go a few times a year to experience these countries.  I'm a software engineer.  A contractor who has been working for this company for 6 months and a U.S. citizen with U.S. passport

Best regards

Comment: Are you a US citizen?  Do you mean while telling your company, in which case you should be asking them this, or while concealing it?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm employed by an agency

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a way to get a visa that includes a work allowance? Because the usual tourist visa does not allow you to work.

Assuming you *can* get one, be prepared that you have to pay taxes *here*. We don't care that you have to pay taxes in the US, too. That is *your* problem. You pay taxes where you work.

So... yes, it's possible. If you get the correct visa and a good tax accountant it is easy. Getting those however, may pose a challenge.

Comment: I have a US passport so I don't need a Visa according to the EU country I want to go to

Comment: @anon77785 Yes... and did you look up what you are allowed to do, when you do "without a visa"? Working is not commonly one of the things.

Comment: For example, I can use ESTA for the US, but that doesn't mean I can just fly over and work there.

Comment: @nvoigt I'll take a look.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @nvoigt It isn't black and white. You can actually come to the US on an ESTA and do some kinds of work. I've done so in the past. Having work related meetings, for instance, does not require you to get a work visa.

Answer (score -2):

I dont see a conflict here at all

Do you acquire a working visa if you go to Mexico for a month and have to connect for work?
You live in US your employer is in US

IMHO, in your current situation - in Europe you are a tourist

@nvoigt - it is not entirely true - see explanation link and description

[Explanation](https://www.supportadventure.com/working-a-us-job-remotely-in-europe-all-you-need-to-know/#:%7E:text=An%20individual%20can%20work%20remotely,will%20become%20a%20tax%20resident.)

> An individual can work remotely for a US company and live in Europe
> for at least 90 days with only a tourist visa. If they stay longer
> than 90 days however, one will need a residence permit and work permit
> for the corresponding country. After residing in one place for over
> 183 days, a person will become a tax resident

@JoeStrazzere work for Mexican employers:

> Most employees accepting a position with your location in Mexico will
> need a permanent resident visa known as the Visa de Residencia
> Permanente. However, not all employees will meet the requirements, as
> they need to have family connections in the country, sufficient
> monthly income, or four years of regular status as a temporary
> resident. It may be wise for companies to apply for a temporary
> resident permit for employees who have been invited to Mexico to work
> or have real estate or close family ties in the country.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere No disrespect here, but do you obtain work visa on vacation or ignore work calls until you back in the country of your employ?

Comment: If you make a single dollar on work performed while in Europe, you are not a tourist and you need a work visa. I have no idea how it works with Mexico, but Mexico is not in Europe.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere its not getting away when it is not required. not logical to tax a person that stays short time in the country while working for long-term employer in the other country

Comment: @nvoigt Could you show me where is it written? all i found is - See edit on the answer

Comment: Well, "Europe" isn't a country, but if you take Germany as an example, [see here](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/visa-service/-/231148). As a US citizen, you don't need a visum, but "Persons who do not require a visa to enter Germany (holders of passports from the countries marked “no” on the list) may not remain on German territory for more than 90 days in any six month period. **Nor may they take up gainful employment whilst here.**". German translations into English are a little clunky at times, but that means you cannot work on those 90 "free" days.

Comment: And by the letter of the law, that means you *can* take up that urgent work call, or visit your German offices and say hi to the colleagues, as long as it's on your vacation time. Even if found out, nobody would raise an eyebrow if you worked one day out of 90 for an emergency back home. But planning to come here and work your normal, regular schedule for example would be illegal and intentional. I'm no lawyer, I cannot tell you whether that's visa fraud or tax fraud or some combination, but it's not allowed, just as it's not allowed were I travelling using ESTA.